# Android: how to convert a scrolling layout to Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-scrollview, drawingcache

I would like to convert the whole scrolling layout inside a ScrollView to a Bitmap

```
<ScrollView...>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

If the content doesn't scroll, this code works great:

```
RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
content.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = content.getDrawingCache();
```

but if the content is scrolling, `getDrawingCache()` returns null.

Any suggestion on how I can export a scrolling view to a bitmap?

Comment: I can see why you're having a problem... it isn't drawing what's off of the screen.  An alternative is creating a bitmap and drawing everything onto it -- but that's rather complex.  Your question intrigues me (as I don't have the answer), but I am wondering what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I would like to convert the layout content to PNG (after converting it to Bitmap), so that I can simply share it as an image via the ACTION_SEND Intent (Email, Facebook, Whatsapp, etc. etc.)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I look forward to an answer as it's not an answer it my toolbox.  Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(content.getWidth(), content.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
content.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: what about if the Custom view used           _scrollTo(mScroller.getCurrX(), mScroller.getCurrY());_

Answer (score 1):

I tried this but it didn't achieve the expected result - had the width of the scrollview, but the height was only part of the scrollview.

What worked instead for me was to do the following:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(content.getChildAt(0).getWidth(), 
content.getChildAt(0).getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
content.draw(canvas);
```